# when kafka consumer get connection?

Tags: java, connection, kafka-consumer-api

I want to know when kafka consumer gets connection.

1. Right after Kafka Consumer Instance was created( ex : `consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>()`
2. Right after consumer `assgin()` or `subscribe()` function was called( ex : `consumer.assgin() or consumer.subscribe()` )
3. Right after consumer `poll()` function was called( ex : `consumer.poll()` )

Comment: The moment you create the connection? In general you often have to setup a connection with credentials/connection string etc in most programming languages. The moment you invoke that connection you often get a connection. So the moment you use consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, In the (new KafkaConsumer) step only construct a KafkaConsumer Object, not to do something.

In the (consumer.subscribe()) Step, Will valid the topic variable. register the listener and set the subscribe type.So then,Neither will not get the connect in this section.

Finally. call the (consumer.poll()) method.this method will get connection and fetch the record.

You can set a error host parameter in kafka config, won't get any exception  ,until call the (consumer.poll()) method